# How to filter the search in Salesforce global search for displaying data of the field in an object

Tags: fields, search

Can we filter the search to show the results of only one field in the particular object in salesforce global search ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you can automatically filter by something every time search is run. But there's something similar that might help you.

[image]

Click that "Customize" button and you'll be able to add runtime filters. I've added 2.

[image]

Comment: thanks for reply but for me it is not showing customize option as in the screen shot you have attached

Comment: Use the sidebar in the search results page to "focus" on Account results, it should appear. You can also access same menu from Setup -> Customize -> Accounts -> Search layouts -> Search filter fields. If you don't see that menu option in setup - check if you have "Customize Application" permission (https://help.salesforce.com/htviewhelpdoc?id=customize_searchlayout.htm)

Comment: Similarly for custom object it'll be one of related lists in the custom object's setup page.